# Unix shell scripting - Copy files alone from parent and sub-folders into a new folder

Tags: unix

I have a parent folder with files and many sub-folders with files. I need to copy files alone from parent and sub-folders to an OutputFolder. Below is the folder structure.

ParentFolder: Parent_1.txt, Parent_2.txt
    SubFolder1: Folder1_1.txt, Folder1_2.txt
    SubFolder2: Folder2_1.txt, Folder2_2.txt

OutputFolder:
Parent_1.txt, Parent_2.txt, Folder1_1.txt, Folder1_2.txt, Folder2_1.txt, Folder2_2.txt

I tried below code, but it copies all the files from sub-folders to parent folder and then move to an OutputFolder. Also, when I call "sh Filename.sh", I get missing argument to `-exec'
cp: cannot stat '20190105'$'\r''/*': No such file or directory.

```
Today=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "today")
mkdir $Today
Yesterday=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "yesterday")
find $Yesterday -iname "*.txt" -exec cp {} $Yesterday \;
cp $Yesterday/* $Today/
```

Request your help on this!

Comment: Pass `-f` option in `find` to search only for files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to copy files alone from parent and sub-folders to an OutputFolder.
>
> I tried below code, but it copies all the files from sub-folders to parent folder

In order to copy the files directly to the *OutputFolder* `$Today`, just specify `$Today` rather than `$Yesterday` after `-exec cp {}`.

> I get missing argument to `-exec' cp: cannot stat '20190105'$'\r''/*': No such file or directory.

The `\r` is a sign of Windows line endings in your script - remove the CRs or save it in Unix format.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.txt" -exec cp "{}" $Yesterday \;
```

to limit the depth to current directory. Mind the quotation marks around curly brackets.